# replace (_)underscore all dot continue by space (. ) in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all the dot continue by space with underscore(_).
example:

```
I/P: 'test. test1. test2'
O/P: 'test_test1_test2'
```

I tried but i can remove dot and space alone only.

```js
//Input
var str = 'test. test1. test2';

//What I have tried
str = str.replace(/\./g,'_');

console.log(str);
//Outputs "test_ test1_ test2"
```

How to write the regex for this?

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\. /g,'_')`? `str = str.replace(/\.\s+/g,'_')`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without RegEx:

```js
let str = "test. test1. test2"
let res = str.split(" ").map(el => el.trim().replace(".", "_")).join("")
    
console.log(res)
```

With RegEx:

```js
let str = "test. test1. test2"
let re = /\.\s+/g

let res = str.replace(re, "_")

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a dot followed by a single space... use `str.replace(/\. /g, "_");`

For a dot followed by multiple spaces... use `str.replace(/\.( )+/g, "_");`

Comment: The group is useless and slows down the process.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the space char:

```js
let IP = 'test. test1. test2'

let OP = IP.replace(/(\.\s+)/g, '_');

console.log(OP)
```

Comment: May I know the reason for the down vote?

Comment: Probably because it doesn't do what was asked. Maybe if you explained why you chose to deviate?

Comment: Also, it looks like you accidentally removed the necessary escaping of `.`. Fixed. (Without the escape `.` will match any character by a line feed.)

Comment: I understand the second point, but how did I 'deviate'?

Comment: `\s` doesn't match (just) a space. It matches one of 25 different white space characters. (The exact number might be different in JavaScript.) That's not necessarily a bad thing. In fact, I'd be more likely to use `\s+` than a literal space. But you gotta explain that :)

Comment: Yes, I get that too! Really thanks!

Comment: (I meant "but a line feed" above)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```js
var input = 'test. test1. test2';

//Delete only ". "
var output = input.replace(/(\.\s)/g, '_');

//Output
console.log(output);
```

If you want only the "space" character, use this instead:

```js
var input = 'test. test1. test2';

//Delete only ". "
var output = input.replace(/(\. )/g, '_');

//Output
console.log(output);
```